AWS ApiGatway http integration authentication
I have an AWS ApiGateway v2 websocket api that sends request to a microservice (deployed on Kubernetes not lambda) using a HTTP integration.
This is working, but now I need to add authentication between the ApiGatway and the microservice. I do not want to authentication for the websocket connection, just the communication between the ApiGateway and microservice.
client <- wss -> api gateway <- http -> microservice

client<->api gateway // no auth needed
api gateway<->microservice // auth required

I control the microservice so I can change how the authentication mechanism works.
One idea I have is to have a lambda that sits between the apigateway and the microservice that adds authentication headers, but I would like to avoid deploying a lambda function if possible.
